# Reversing a variant animation in framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have an animation set in a variant that triggers on `whileHover`, but when I un-hover, the animation reverses in a way that is different than the transition settings I have set up.

Is there a way to have the animation reverse with the same transition settings and variant approach I have described?

[Codesandbox Here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverse-whilehover-framer-motion-l3zx9y?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. If you want to use the same transition for all variants, you can move it out of the variant declaration and just add it to the motion component using the `transition` prop.

```
const childVariants = {
  start: {
    scaleX: 1
  },
  end: {
    scaleX: -1,
    // no transition here
  }
};
```

```
<motion.div
  key={i}
  variants={childVariants}
  style={{
    width: "50px",
    height: "50px",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }}
  // transition here will be used for everything
  transition={{
    type: "tween",
    ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
    duration: 2
  }}
/>
```

2. You want to set the `animate` prop to the variant (or values) to animate to after hover. `initial` sets the initial state of the component, but `animate` defines what to animate *to* (from `initial` or `hover` or whatever).

In your case that looks like this:

```
<motion.div
  animate={"start"}
  whileHover={"end"}
  transition={{ staggerChildren: 0.2 }}
  style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
>
    {renderChildren}
</motion.div>
```